# Crash report from google play on monodroid application

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have received this this crash report on my goole play console:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.maps.PixelConverter.toPixels(PixelConverter.java:71)
at com.google.android.maps.PixelConverter.toPixels(PixelConverter.java:61)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onLayout(MapView.java:727)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2132)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1951)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1164)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4845)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is a java stack trace and my code is on the monodroid and by c#. How can I detect what is my problem?

Comment: Do you have any references to static variables outside of the visible activity? Removing them is a good start.

Comment: I have many variables in the application class. is that the problem?

Comment: Normal variables that are contained within their own scope won't be a problem. It only becomes problem when memory runs low in android, activities in background are wiped out. When the app is restored from background, the visible activity still has reference to other static variables from other activities that are already gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see first line of crash report:`java.lang.NullPointerException`

One method interrupted with an exception, so some global variables not instantiate and remain `null`. so application cause with crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are mixing Maps API v2 and deprecated v1. com.google.android.maps.MapView is a class from the old API.

Comment: MapView is available in Maps API v2: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView. It does require more effort by the programmer however.